# Iphone 6 plus IOS 8 will only display the apple logo when turned on or connected to computer

Tags: iphone

after the logo is displayed it will shut off again. Interesting leading up to this problem my phone was having some display problems, it would not show the background on the lock screen then it would freeze after the password was typed in. I did drop it on a wood floor earlier... But nothing too hard. Interested in any fixes that don't involve going to a store or repair shop.
Thanks
Update
I pressed the home and lock buttons until the apple logo cycled twice then the connect to itunes logo appeared,
last time this happened I pressed both the buttons again until the lock screen appeared.
This time I connected to itunes, it said the iphone will be updated but may need to be restored.
It is now updating

Comment: What did the 'genius' at the store say?

Answer (score 1):

This likely will not help everyone experiencing this type of issue, but this is how I got it working again.
Once I saw the connect to itunes screen, I did that.
Next it started on its update
After the main download and install it displayed a load bar under the apple logo again
Now its working, its updated
hope this helps someone